# How to get specific number of rows based on column values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

Suppose I have a MNIST dataset in this way.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
data = df.loc[df['label'].isin([1,6])]
```

I am trying to select only those rows whose column ['label'] == 1 or 6.

But, I am want to get only 500 rows from each column ['label']

How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe try something like `df.loc[df['label'].iloc[0:500].isin([1,6])]`...

Comment: Do you mean the first 500 rows? Then  df[df.label.isin([1,6]))[0:500] will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can group them and select the number you want for each value:

```
data = df.loc[df['label'].isin([1,6])].groupby('label').head(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby first then filer i.e

```
ndf= df.groupby('label').head(500)
data = ndf.loc[ndf['label'].isin([1,6])]
```